# How do I debug an ASPNET Core MVC Application Deployed in Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I've created a simple ASPNET Core 1.0 MVC app, which I am trying to deploy to Azure using Visual Studio.  I am able to run this app locally on my machine using IIS Express, and navigate to my default route and display the page.  However, in Azure I always get a 500 error every time, and at this point I am at a loss for how to get additional information.

I've enabled detailed request logging in my Azure app, but it doesn't really seem to tell me much.

```
ModuleName="AspNetCoreModule", Notification="EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER", HttpStatus="500", HttpReason="Internal Server Error", HttpSubStatus="0", ErrorCode="The operation completed successfully.
 (0x0)", ConfigExceptionInfo=""
```

I've stripped down my Startup configuration to the bare essentials

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggingFactory)
{

    loggingFactory.AddConsole();
    loggingFactory.AddDebug();

    app.UseMvc(routes => {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
        );
    });

}
```

Something must be blowing up in the MVC pipeline but I have no idea how to add more visibility.  What can I do to get more information?

And in case it matters, this is my `Program.cs`

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseKestrel()
    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .UseIISIntegration()
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

Comment: I'm not using a database if that's what you're asking

Comment: The first two things I would try will be to change the environment to Development, so that it will display the developer exception page. Then maybe you could try to debug remotely the azure web app - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/11/04/remote-debugging-a-window-azure-web-site-with-visual-studio-2013/

Comment: Is this not the most frustrating feeling??? I've been trying to navigate around this 500 error for hours. If you got your site working, I'd be very glad to hear your solution, @MikeC. Thanks.

Comment: @MikeC did you find an answer to this error?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try setting `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to `Development` to display full exception message on the error page.

[image: Application Settings]

**Remember** to turn it off when finished, otherwise you will leak error information.