# DotNet Core web app working locally but not when deployed to Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, webdeploy, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to build a new web app using DotNet Core.
The app is Web API + AngularJS with ui-router.

The same app was working correctly both locally and on Azure using ASP.NET 5.
When I updated, I fixed a lot of stuff and got the new app working locally.
However, on Azure, I have the following error whenever I try to do any action:
"The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

I searched for the error online and tried to use the provided solutions but in vain (e.g.: [ASP.NET Core app not working after publish to Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39209335/asp-net-core-app-not-working-after-publish-to-azure)).

I did not post any code here because honestly I don't know where to start and what to post. Could someone please advise?

Regards,

Comment: And if you delete the app completely and recreate it again?

Comment: I haven't really tried that... It's a bit of a pain... but if you say it should work, I can give it a try

Comment: It should work....and for example, let's say that if you don't do that, you can resolve this issue in like, two more days...delete an recreate the app takes a lot less than days....

Comment: Ok I am working on that now... will let you know the outcome. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: That did not work. I also used an SQL server db on Azure to replace the sqlite one I was using in vain. I am new to this. Is there anywhere to check the logs on the server? Do you have another idea?

Answer (score 2):

In case someone was facing the same issue:

1. I was able to detect the problem by following this link ([How do I debug an ASPNET Core MVC Application Deployed in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38749168/how-do-i-debug-an-aspnet-core-mvc-application-deployed-in-azure))
2. This helped me detect that it was not able to find node_modules
3. I added the node_modules directory to the publishOptions -> include

It worked!

Regards,